# How to insert many elements into DOM using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, dom

Pulling my hair out here...

I need to insert a bunch of html into another set set of html at two distinct points, using PHP.

$a is returned to me from another class's function. I need to insert $b into $a, making the $b elements the parent of some of $a's elements.

```
<?php
$a = '
<div id="one">
    <div id="two">
        <div id="three">Hi</div>
    </div>
</div> 
';

$b = '
<div id="red">
    <div id="blue"></div>
</div>
<div id="green">
    <div id="yellow">there</div>
</div>
';
?>
```

Need to end up with:

```
<?php
$c = '
<div id="one">
    <div id="two">
        <div id="red">
            <div id="blue">
                <div id="three">Hi</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="green">
            <div id="yellow">there</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
';
?>
```

Note how $b is inserted into $a, making all of $b a child to "two". But at the same time, "three" becomes a child of "blue". "green" and "yellow" maintain their original relationship, but are now nested under "two".

Real world example....

```
<?php
$a = '
<div class="ginput_complex ginput_container">
    <span class="ginput_full">
            <input name="input_5" id="input_4_5" type="file" value="" class="medium" tabindex="5">
            <label for="input_4_5" class="ginput_post_image_file">File</label>
    </span>
    <span class="ginput_full ginput_post_image_title">
            <input type="text" name="input_5.1" id="input_4_5_1" value="" tabindex="6">
            <label for="input_4_5_1">Title</label>
    </span>
    <span class="ginput_full ginput_post_image_caption">
            <input type="text" name="input_5.4" id="input_4_5_4" value="" tabindex="7">
            <label for="input_4_5_4">Caption</label>
    </span>
    <span class="ginput_full ginput_post_image_description">
            <input type="text" name="input_5.7" id="input_4_5_7" value="" tabindex="8">
            <label for="input_4_5_7">Description</label>
    </span>
</div>
';


$b =
'
<div class="container">
    <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
        <div class="span7">
            <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
            <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>

            {{{{{{{{ THIS IS WHERE I MY FILE INPUT SHOULD GO }}}}}}}}}}}

            </span>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                <span>Start upload</span>
            </button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
                <span>Cancel upload</span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
                <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                <span>Delete</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
';

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($a);
$x = new DOMXPath($doc);

?>
```

I'm using $x->query('//*[@id="input_4_5"]') to get to the node I want to start working on. And from there, I've been using new DOMElement and importNode with variations of appendChild, replaceChild, and insertBefore to try an traverse the DOM tree. But frankly, even if I did traverse it successfully, I can't figure out how to insert/append the large blocks of code that I'm working with.

Comment: if you are playing with `dom` consider using `javascript`

Comment: I considered javascript, but all of my variables are on the server, are set, and don't require user input. So I'd really like to do this on the server side.

Comment: Take a look at [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: Have you tried using [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: how are you getting the values of `$a` and `$b` are you hardcoding it like above ? can you show us how you construct `$a` and `$b` ?

Comment: always use javascript when trying to manipulate the DOM; if you want to use javascript; tell me and i will help you

Comment: @Deepak, $a comes from another class's function and I don't have control over it. I have control over $b.

Comment: @IonutFlaviusPogacian, everything that I need is on the server, so I haven't tried to justify moving it to the client pipeline for processing. However, I may be doing so soon. Thank you.

Comment: Do you just want the file input, or the surrounding `span` too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using the [SimpleHTMLDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) parser

Try this:

```
<?php
require_once( 'simple_html_dom.php' );

$a = '
<div id="one">
    <div id="two">
        <div id="three">Hi</div>
    </div>
</div> 
';

$b = '
<div id="red">
    <div id="blue"></div>
</div>
<div id="green">
    <div id="yellow">there</div>
</div>
';

$a = str_get_html( $a );
$c = str_get_html( $b );

$c->find( 'div[id=blue]', 0 )->innertext = $a->find( 'div[id=two]', 0 )->innertext;
$a->find( 'div[id=two]', 0 )->innertext = $c->save();

echo $a;
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Check below code, i have used php & jQuery for generation of output.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="varA" style="display:none">
<?
    echo $a= '<div id="one">
    <div id="two">
        <div id="three">Hi</div>
    </div>
</div>';
?>
</div>
<div id="varB" style="display:none">
<?
    echo $b = '
<div id="red">
    <div id="blue"></div>
</div>
<div id="green">
    <div id="yellow">there</div>
</div>
';
?>
</div>

<span id="output"></span>

<script language="javascript">
alert('varA id have:'+$('#varA').html());
var middle = $('#two').html();
$('#output').html($('#varA').html());
$('#varA').remove();
alert('varB id have:'+$('#varB').html());
$('#two').html($('#varB').html());
$('#varB').remove();
$('#blue').html(middle);
alert('output id have:'+$('#output').html());
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to write a new function to get the data about `a` and `b`, and then generate the html.

Comment: $a comes from another class's function and I don't have control over it.

Answer (score 0):

if i had to do it i would make a placeholder, something line `/#/` and then do ma str_replace on it.

But if you really need to use DOM, check out DOMDocument.

If you want to do Javascript echo them out in your js

```
<script>

var a = '<?php echo $a ?>';
var b = '<?php echo $b ?>':

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Does replacing the string will help?

```
$matched = array();
preg_match('/<div id="three">.*?<\/div>/', $a, $matched);
$b = preg_replace('/<div id="blue"><\/div>/', '<div id="blue">'.$matched[0].'</div>', $b);
$a = str_replace($matched[0], $b, $a);
```